# How many tight constraints does a linear program have?

Tags: linear-programming

I have the following constraints of a linear program:

$$\sum_{j=1}^{m}x_{ij}=1,\quad\quad1\le i\le n,$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}p_i^k x_{ij}=1,\quad\quad1\le j\le m,\;1\le k\le d,$$
$$x_{ij}\ge 0,\quad\quad1\le i\le n,\;1\le j\le m,$$

The paper I am reading states the following:

> The number of variables in our LP is $nm$. The number of nontrivial
>   constraints (those that are other than $x_{ij} \ge 0$) is ($n+dm$). From standard polyhedral theory [28] any basic (vertex) solution to our LP has $nm$ tight constraints.

Why is this? What is the general claim and its proof of this? I mean, why there is $nm$ tight constraints for any basic solution?

---

The paper is this one: [On Multi-dimensional Packing Problems](http://repository.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1080&context=cis_papers). You can find the quotation in page 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tight constraint seems to be that an inequality $\alpha^\top x \ge \beta$ is fulfilled as equality, $\alpha^\top x = \beta$.

I am not familiar with polyhedral theory to know why this is the case here.